# Prime number proof

Tags: prime-numbers

Given that $n>2$. Prove that if $2^n-1$ is prime then $2^n+1$ is composite or vice versa. 
I looked on wikipedia on Fermat number and Mersenne prime, but I still don't know how they work.

Answer (score 2):

**Hint** $\ a\mid (a\!-\!1)^n\!\pm 1\ $ since $ $ mod $\ a\!:\ (a\!-\!1)^n \equiv (-1)^n\equiv \pm 1$

e.g. $\,\ 10\mid 9^n\pm1\, $ is a well-known case (power's of $9$ end with digit $1$ or $9)$

Your case can be viewed as the analogy in radix $\,3.$

Answer (score 1):

Clearly you can't prove that $2^n-1$ composite implies $2^n+1$ is prime.  Take $n=6$, for example.  Going the other way, think about divisibility by $3$.

Comment: I'm not sure what the OP meant by "or vice versa".  I suspect they probably meant "and if $2^n+1$ is prime then $2^n-1$ is composite", in other words just the contrapositive of the first statement.

Comment: @David:  I took it as "if $2^n-1$ is prime then $2^n+1$ is composite", but I can see your reading as well.  I think mine would be the more standard English reading of vice versa.

Comment: Maybe I didn't understand the question right. It asks "Prove that if one of the number 2^n−1 and 2^n+1 is prime, where n>2, then the other is composite."

Comment: Ok, take a look at the pattern of remainders when you divide $2^n-1$ and $2^n+1$ by $3$.  Just make a table for small $n$.  See if you can find a pattern, then prove it.

Comment: Interesting. Thanks for the help. I'll take a look at the modular route.

Answer (score 1):

At least one of $2^n-1$ and $2^n+1$ must be divisible by $3$, and neither of them is $3$. Thus, at least one of them is composite.

Comment: As simple and short as that. +1